# Update of large table times out without errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble with a script that is supposed to populate a date field with the value of another date field in another table. (the table being populated contains over 182 million records) The script keeps stopping after about an hour or so without generating any errors. I've tried adding all the timeout exceptions I could think of, but to no avail. (I have to use dynamic settings since I don't have access to the DB server to change the .ini settings) Can anyone give me an idea of what's going wrong? Here's my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$dbname = "rismedia_newsletter";
include('db_connect.php');
ignore_user_abort(1);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 28800);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 28800);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('max_input_time', -1);
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

$sql = "SELECT `ad_stats`.`id`, `newsletters`.`send_date` 
        FROM ad_stats 
            INNER JOIN newsletters ON (`ad_stats`.`newsletter_id` = `newsletters`.`id`) 
        WHERE `ad_stats`.`send_date` IS NULL 
           OR send_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
        GROUP BY `ad_stats`.`newsletter_id`";

$res = $db -> query($sql);
while ($row = $res -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $send_date = $row['send_date'];
    if ($send_date > '') {
        $qupd = "UPDATE ad_stats SET send_date = '".$send_date."' WHERE id= ".$id;
        $upd = $db -> query ($qupd);
    } else { 
        continue; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you look at any of the error logs?

Comment: What's the `GROUP BY` for?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just combine the queries (Select & Update) and send it as one massive updates statement instead of a loop.  Set based processing is much faster than record-by-record and less network overhead.

Comment: In the absence of a any aggregating functions, I'm not sure what the GROUP BY clause is doing.

Comment: Because I don't have access to the server, I'm unable to check the logs. The GROUP BY is used to prevent too many records caused by the JOIN and to prevent duplicates. It's not really necessary, just something I added to try and speed things up a bit. I can easily do without it. Combining the SELECT and UPDATE statements is, quite frankly, something I hadn't even considered. DUH me. I'll give it a shot, thanks a bunch everyone. (is there a way to accept a comment as the preferred answer?)

Comment: Hate to be a bother but I've never combined an UPDATE with a SELECT while using a JOIN and a WHERE clause before. This is what I wrote, but I'm not sure it's correct. Does it look ok to you guys?

    "UPDATE ad_stats a JOIN newsletters b ON a.newsletter_id = b.id SET a.send_date = b.send_date WHERE a.send_date IS NULL;"

Comment: Just as an FYI, GROUP BY would possibly remove duplicates if your newsletter ids are not unique, but would actually make the query slower since the database engine would need to work to group the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you should combine them into one query for faster processing.

MySQL:

```
UPDATE 
    ad_stats a 
    JOIN newsletters b ON a.newsletter_id = b.id 
SET 
    a.send_date = b.send_date 
WHERE 
    a.send_date IS NULL OR 
    a.send_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Postgres:

```
UPDATE
    ad_stats
SET
    send_date = N.send_date
FROM
    ad_stats A
    INNER JOIN newsletters N ON A.newsletter_id = N.id
WHERE
    A.send_date IS NULL OR 
    A.send_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

It should be MUCH faster this way but if it still fails after a while it might be a server setting, which you said you might not be able to change. If that's the case, you may have to run your script in smaller batches using a LIMIT and run it multiple times until you are done. It might also help to make sure that you have indexes for ad_stats.newsletter_id and newsletters.id.

Comment: That looks like it's perfect. I'm going to accept this answer for now and I'll let you know how it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Cubis, I received an error in my syntax just before the WHERE clause. After a few changes, I came up with this which is working. (just have to see if it times out or not)

"UPDATE ad_stats a JOIN newsletters b ON a.newsletter_id = b.id SET a.send_date = b.send_date WHERE a.send_date IS NULL OR a.send_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';"

Comment: AH I put in the wrong syntax (postgres vs mysql) - I'll update my answer to contain both for future readers